# Zigbee network - Joining several brands to a network

Tags: zigbee

I'm new to Zigbee, and I iwsh to create a Zigbee network.
I bought a Sonoff Zigbee dongle to connect it to a Home Assistant (on raspberryPi), and now I want to buy Zigbee devices.

How can I tell if an end device will connect / pair to my network (before buying it odcourse)?

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the device on https://zigbee.blakadder.com/

You can then check for compatibility with ZHA of Zigbee2MQTT depending on how you setup your Sonoff dongle.